# How to compare timestamp data type with string in postgres?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, timestamp

I have date and time stored in postgres as timestamp format in postgres like this:

```
created_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
```

now I want to search for rows that have `created_time` between `date_before` and `date_after` fields. both these fields are query strings.

How can i filter data with this?

Comment: In what format the strings are?

Comment: just date and time without timestamp

Comment: `2020-06-22 19:10:25-07`

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you can simply compare the timestamp with the strings:

```sql
select *
from your_table
where created_time >= '2020-06-22 19:10:25-07'
and created_time < '2020-06-23 19:10:25-07'
```

Remember [not to use between with time stamps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29)

Comment: @Kayaman No it doesn't. The problem with between happens when timestamps are compared with dates without time. OP stated he was to compare date with times

Comment: @rudeTool I just realised that your column is a timestamp **without** time zone. You should use timestamp **with** time zone as you are trying to compare timestamps with time zones.

Comment: my query params doesnt have timezone

Comment: Please see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29
Using TS without TZ is a bad practice.

Comment: Also the example TS you put in your question comment has a time zone

Comment: @Kayaman The problem with between happens when timestamps are compared with dates without time. OP stated he was to compare date with times.

Comment: note that I said "without time" and not "without time zone"

Comment: so Incase I have stored timestamp with timezone,can i use your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can use it.

Comment: @Kayaman can you post your answer so that I can review it too

Comment: Ok, I see your point, but the problem with between is its implicitly included boundaries, and the awkward comparison between date and datetime. In this case it is explicit and safe. I have edited the question for best practices though.